# Yii - Compare rules for password fail in case of empty value

Tags: php, validation, yii, passwords

I want to create a page to change user password that accept empty values:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'password'); ?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password',
                            array('maxlength'=>256, 'value'=>'', 'placeholder'=>'...')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'password'); ?>

<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'password_repeat'); ?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password_repeat',
                            array('maxlength'=>256, 'value'=>'', 'placeholder'=>'...')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'password_repeat'); ?>
```

This is the rule to compare password:

```
array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password_repeat',
            'message'=>'xxx', 'allowEmpty'=>true,
            'on'=>'register, login, index'),
array('password_repeat', 'safe'),
array('password_repeat', 'length', 'max'=>256, 'tooLong'=>'...',
            'on'=>'register, index, login'),
```

The problem is that validation always fail when I left the password fiends empty, why?

Comment: Have you tried to set the password_repeat 'allowEmpty'=>true ?

Comment: I applied it on 'length' rule and nothing changed :(.

Comment: Try `array('password_repeat, password', 'safe'),`. Assuming you have allowEmpty on both length and compare I don't see what else could be causing the issue.

Comment: What validation error does the field return? you can see this with var_dump($model->errors) I think

Comment: Also try to put the compare value in the password repeat rule array

Comment: Try to remove `array('password_repeat', 'safe'),`. Also you can follow [This link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/) for more information.

Comment: The error return is the 'xxx' message that I defined above.

Comment: I removed it and nothing changed, hamed.

Comment: Maybe make your own validation function.

Comment: For the well-known 'compare' rule that everybody use?

Comment: If you remove the message, it should return a default message on which you can determine what is at fault here.

Comment: Ok, I get the answer. I tried to do this: I left the passwords field empty. If user enter anything on it, I update their passwords. If not, I make no change. The problem is that if I do not assign the value from the form to model instance (in this case it's empty value), it will use the value retrieved from database. And this value is certainly different with default value of 'password_repeat' (empty in this case). Thank you for all your help.

Comment: ahhh, Yeah I had the same problem, but could not remember what was wrong (its 2 years ago) but now I remember. Good luck with your site!

Comment: May be your scenario doesn't apply there

Comment: @VeritatisCupitor Maby next time post your controller function as well. That would have helped a lot.